# Is the OS kernel part of the main() of the OS or is it a seperate function?

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling, os-kernel

I am wondering is usually the OS kernel which provides a link between 2 processes part of the main() of the os or is it a seperate function?In other words do we usually  encapsulate the OS kernel in the main or we use a seperate function?

Comment: This question appears to be unanswerable, because there are too many wrong assumptions. For instance, "the OS kernel which provides a link between two processes" - that's not a single thing, and the things which do provide those links together make up only part of the OS kernel.

Comment: @MSalters hmm there IS a part of code which provides link between  2 processes I dont understand you.

Comment: There are many "links". E.g. parent process ID (might not be a kernel thing, can be managed by init), shared memory (page table entry in CPU), pipes (kernel), sockets (kernel), messages (typically not a kernel thing).

Comment: Yes we can make interprocess communication by a)shared memory or b)links between 2 processes and as a middleman we have the OS kernel.

Comment: You are inventing a term here ("link") that is meaningless to us. I suggest you look for a textbook on OS and computer basics. If you don't speak the same language, you can't ask good questions, nor can you understand answers.

Comment: I am referring to this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJuYKfR8vec&pp=ygUuaW50ZXJwcm9jZXNzIGNvbW11bmljYXRpb24gaW4gb3BlcmF0aW5nIHN5c3RlbQ%3D%3D